# Can i use auto or decltype instead trailing return type?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, trailing-return-type

I find `trailing return type` so easy to define the return of a function that returns a complicated types e.g:

```
auto get_diag(int(&ar)[3][3])->int(&)[3]{ // using trailing return type
    static int diag[3]{
        ar[0][0], ar[1][1], ar[2][2]
    };
    return diag;
}

auto& get_diag2(int(&ar)[3][3]){ // adding & auto because otherwise it converts the array to pointer
    static int diag[3]{
        ar[0][0], ar[1][1], ar[2][2]
    };
    return diag;
}

int main(){

    int a[][3]{
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6},
        {7, 8, 9}
    };

    decltype(get_diag(a)) diag{
        get_diag(a)
    };

    for (auto i : diag)
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    decltype(get_diag2(a)) diag2{
        get_diag2(a)
    };

    for (auto i : diag2)
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;


    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

- I want to know what is the difference between the functions `get_diag` and `get_diag2`. So as long as the output is the same why I need to use trailing return type?

Comment: `get_diag2` should not compile unless you are using C++14 or later.  Are you sure you are compiling with C++11?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yes you are true. When I tried it on C++11 compiler it fails complaining about: ` 'auto' return without trailing return type; deduced return types are a C++14 extension`. please add it as an answer So that it maybe useful for other OPs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
auto& get_diag2(int(&ar)[3][3]){ // adding & auto because otherwise it converts the array to pointer
    static int diag[3]{
        ar[0][0], ar[1][1], ar[2][2]
    };
    return diag;
}
```

Will not work in a C++11 compiler.  Using `auto` without a trailing return type was added to C++14 and acts like how auto works when using it for a variable.  This means it will never return a reference type so you have to use `auto&` to return a reference to the thing you want to return.

If you do not know if you should return a reference or a value (this happens a lot in generic programming) then you can use `decltyp(auto)` as the return type.  For example

```
template<class F, class... Args>
decltype(auto) Example(F func, Args&&... args) 
{ 
    return func(std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
}
```

will return by value if `func` returns by value and return by reference if `func` returns a reference.

---

In short if you are using C++11 you have to specify the return type, either in front or as a trailing return type.  In C++14 and above you can just use `auto`/`decltype(auto)` and let the compiler deal with it for you.