# Does decltype(auto) make trailing return type obsolete?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, trailing-return-type, decltype-auto

There have been [many](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42744245/7151494), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58006975/7151494), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55753000/7151494) questions and answers regarding the *trailing return type*, `auto` return type deduction and the very useful `decltype(auto)`. But I failed to find an answer to whether the *trailing return type* is needed **at all** since we have `decltype(auto)`. Are there cases that the trailing return type solves, where `decltype(auto)` either cannot be used or doesn't work (gives unexpected / incorrect results) **and** the trailing return type was needed in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point of this question. Let's say someone comes along and provides some corner case where you need both an explicit return type definition and for that return type to be trailing. What would that mean? How would that in any way affect how people code? I don't see the point in any declaration of it being "obsolete" or not.

Comment: @NicolBolas I had a somewhat biased view of trailing returned type, just `auto` and `decltype(auto)` in function signatures. I was under the impression that trailing return type was, apart from potentially introducing more readable syntax, meant to solve some problems regarding, for example, value categories of the returned type. `decltype(auto)` solves that. I then came across some SFINAE examples that used trailing return type and I thought it was a necessity (I think it was hinted in the source). Regardless, I see that it's not the case. So you have suggestions how to improve my question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`decltype(auto)` (and more generally deduced return type) and trailing return type are orthogonal features.

You can have:

- `decltype(auto) f() {}`
- `auto f() -> decltype(auto) {}`

### Trailing return type

trailing return type is fine especially to have access to context we don't have before the function name

- as for template:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  auto f(T x) -> decltype(bar(x));
  ```

  versus

  ```
  template <typename T>
  decltype(bar(std::declval<T&>())) f(T x);
  ```
- or for dependent name in class:

  ```
  auto C::begin() -> iterator;
  ```

  versus

  ```
  C::iterator C::begin();
  ```

The only place where it is required is for lambda (if you have/want to specify return type explicitly):

- `[]() -> some_type {/*...*/}`
- `[]() -> auto {/*...*/}` (which is equivalent to `[]() {/*...*/}`)
- `[]() -> decltype(auto) {/*...*/}`

Case when we have to defining return type of lambda is when it should return reference type.

### Deduced return type

Done with `decltype(auto)` and `auto`.

`decltype(auto)` and `auto` deduction type differs, mostly as `T&&` and `T`.

Deduced return type requires definition of the body.

They also doesn't allow SFINAE, as there are no *substitution*.

Comment: So, to summarise, there are **no** situations where you absolutely **must** use trailing return type, correct? That's pretty much the only thing I care about (unless the answer is *no* - then I'd appreciate an example very much).

Comment: @Fureeish: I found one situation where trailing return type is required: lambda, as we cannot have the type before. But again unrelated to deduction return type.

Comment: Else you can transform `auto f() -> Ret` into `Ret f()` possibly by changing syntax for `Ret`

Comment: Thank you. That's the answer to my question.

Comment: @Fureeish: "*there are no situations where you absolutely must use trailing return type, correct*" Outside of lambdas, there have *never* been situations in C++ where you "absolutely must use trailing return types". It was always a convenience feature, used to reduce repetition and make code more legible.

Answer (score 6):

The trivial example would be a situation when you want to invoke function before it is defined and returned type is deduced:

```
decltype(auto) bar(); // doesn't help

decltype(auto) foo() { bar(); } // error: returned type of `bar` is unknown

decltype(auto) bar() { foo(); }
```

Comment: And the trailing return type solves the problem in this example how exactly?

Comment: @Fureeish This case is solved by explicit returned type. Trailing returned type may be preferred in this situation in case of class members. So it is not obsolete.

Comment: That was not my question, sorry. I think I made it pretty clear. I mention no explicit returned type in my question.

Comment: railing return type is not the same as trailing auto. You can specify the trailing return type explicitly, so @VTT's answer is correct

Comment: That means I should've phrased my question differently. I meant the situation where we have to use a trailing return type **and** we cannot use `decltype(auto)`. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @Fureeish It is wrong to contrapose `decltype(auto)` and trailing return type.  There are plenty of situations when deduced return type won't work and explicit return type is required but there are no situations when explicit return type is required to be trailing (though use of trailing return type may simplify things). Also note that `decltype(auto)` can be a trailing return type as well.

Comment: @VTT What if your return type is dependent on the type of some expression involving your function arguments? And it doesn't consist of single simple `return`. Or if you want SFINAE?

Comment: Basically what @DanM said. I've seen some examples, primarily (IIRC) regarding SFINAE, but I am unable to find those. I would love to - that would simplify and clarify my question immensly.

Comment: @DanM. Sorry, I have hard time following your question. It is not possible to write functions with deduced returned types and a circular dependency on each other. Returned type must be defined explicitly at some point. I don't see how having fancy return type deduction will change anything.

Comment: @VTT I was replying to your statement that `Note that there is no situation when explicit return type is required to be trailing`. To my knowledge the things I've listed above require trailing return type. I.e. `auto foo(T a, E b) -> decltype(a + b) { return a + b; }` where you also want to SFINAE on `a + b`, or if there is another return in the function body with non-deducible type (yet you know it's the same as of `a + b`.

Comment: @DanM. But `decltype(a + b)` is not an explicit return type.

Comment: @VTT How is it not?

Comment: @DanM. Because it is getting deduced from arguments, isn't it?

Comment: @VTT it's still explicit. Not named, but explicit. It says that the function has this specific type. If it wasn't dependent on the function arguments but on something else (say, `a` and `b` were globals), it wouldn't change anything.

Comment: @DanM. Well, I consider any situation when returned type getting deduced not explicit. So "Note that there is no situation when explicit return type is required to be trailing" does not apply to something like `auto foo(T a, E b) -> decltype(a + b)`.